# Creating a dictionary from a text file with the items on separate lines within the text file (Python 3+)

Tags: python, dictionary

I am doing a lab for my programming class and can't figure out the proper statements to make this work:

Write a program that first reads in the name of an input file and then reads the input file using the `file.readlines()` method. The input file contains an unsorted list of number of seasons followed by the corresponding TV show. Your program should put the contents of the input file into a dictionary where the number of seasons are the keys, and a list of TV shows are the values (since multiple shows could have the same number of seasons).

Sort the dictionary by key (least to greatest) and output the results to a file named output_keys.txt, separating multiple TV shows associated with the same key with a semicolon (`;`).

example: if input is file1.txt and the contents are:

```
20
Gunsmoke
30
The Simpsons
10
Will & Grace
14
Dallas
20
Law & Order
12
Murder, She Wrote
```

The output.txt should contain:

```
10: Will & Grace
12: Murder, She Wrote
14: Dallas
20: Gunsmoke; Law & Order
30: The Simpsons
```

The code I am given is:

```
my_dict = {}

# Type your code to read from the file and create a dictionary here

# Sort by keys (years) from least amount of years to greatest amount of years

my_dict_sorted_by_keys = dict(sorted(my_dict.items()))

# Type your code to write to file here
```

I haven't tried much because I don't have a clue how to pair items from a dictionary that are on separate lines. I understand how to open and read the file, I just don't know how to create the dictionary. Sorry if I'm wasting your time, I am a pretty big nub with this stuff. I don't need you to give me the solution necessarily (unless you want to), I just would like a push in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: Write a while loop that keeps going until there are no more lines in a file to read. On each iteration read two lines from the file at a time. Line 1 is the `key`, line two is the `value`. If the key isn't already in the dictionary do: `my_dict[key] = value` otherwise do `my_dict[key] += ';' + value`. Don't forget to convert the `key` to an `int` so it will sort properly.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't have a clue how to pair items from a dictionary that are on separate lines

`readlines()` will return you a list of lines. Take that list and iterate through it using [for loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop).

Simple way how to pair the number and the name is to create helper variables for both of these, check if they are empty or not and decide what to do upon that. I'm not give you the code, but the principle is something like this:

- have variables like `latest_number` and `latest_name` with an empty values
- inside each cycle for loop:
- first check if `latest_number` is empty. If it is, assign the value of current line into it
- otherwise check if `latest_name` is empty. If it is, assign the value of current line into it.
- check if both `latest_number` and `latest_name` have a non-empty value. If they do, you can add them into a dictionary, and unset them again, so you will be ready for the next pair of values on the next lines. But first you have to check if there is any value in the dictionary for the current `latest_number`, and if so you have to concatenate the values together rather than overwrite it.

I bet you'll have a lot of questions "but how do I do this?", so remember - googling is your friend.